# Why the font are pixelated after exporting from photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

So I created one banner in photoshop. I exported it as photoshop PDF last year. when I open that in acrobat it is perfect. but recently I have had to export it again but when I open it in acrobat the font is pixelated.

PSD settings: 1754px X 2480px (300ppi)

My export setting: Save as copy -> Adobe PDF -> Adobe PDF setting: HIGH quality print

1. last year exported PDF. I actually didn't remember which setting I changed to export this type quality pdf.
   [image: last year exported PDF]
2. latest exported PDF. Adobe PDF setting: HIGH quality print. I also try to set compression option to DoNotDownscale and Compression: None
   [image: Recently exported PDF]

Anyone know how can I acheive 1 photo type of quality?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's difficult to say for sure without access to your file, but the text has been rasterized for some reason.  Do you have any effects on the text layer, or did you rasterize the text layer, or did you flatten the layers? Can you show us a screenshot of the layers in Photoshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is resolved. The fonts are Faux bold that why it is pixelated in export. I turned it off. now exported font is no more pixelated no matter how much I zoom. Also thanks for your help.